# Sudo access to another user's account

Tags: permissions, sudo, accounts

what will be the most efficient way for multiple users (around 15) to be able to sudo to another user's account to run privileged commands?

so to make it clear, I have a main user called `mainaccount` that has sudo/root access, I also have 15 other users that need to be able to change or run commands  `su - mainaccount` for managing a test environment.

how can I do this?

Edit: I am asking how is this done, so if user `user1` wants to run a command as `mainaccount` (su - mainaccount) but without putting mainaccount's password, rather using their own password. I guess kind of like the `wheel` group, where you can add multiple users but this one just to be able to change or run commands as mainaccount

Comment: Are you asking how is it done? Or how do you make running it better? I guess I am confused by what you want clarified. Did you want people to just run individual commands? Or did you want to have them to run as many as they need without relogging in?

Comment: The su command stands for :switch user. To use the su command on a single command basis, enter:

  su user -c command

To switch users so you can enter many commands enter:

  su user

Replace user with mainaccount for the above example.

I am posting this as a comment as I don't really know what your question was. But this at least helps you with your syntax.

Comment: Keep in mind that if `mainaccount` can become root (passwordlessly), then anyone who can become `mainaccount` can become root.  That said, set up a group for the users, and in `sudoers`, set up a stanza saying "members of _this_ group can `sudo su - mainaccount`."

Comment: I guess this is pretty close to what I want, I do want the main account to become root (which I've done that by adding it to the wheel group) but now, I want to put all the users, so they are able to run commands as the `mainaccount` how do I escpefically add the users so they can su - mainaccount?

Comment: I think that identity and non-repudiation is a big deal. The real use of `sudo` is to configure the execution of specific elevated commands to specific users and/or groups. If you engineer a method for users to first become another user before using `sudo`, you'll have a hard time learning or proving who did what. Why not focus on configuring `sudo` commands for a certain group, and put your users in that group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That (and making back-ups) is pretty much the traditional use of the **operator** user and group...

Set up a group - eg. **mainusers** - and add the users allowed to "become" **mainaccount**

In */etc/sudoers* add: 
`%mainusers ALL = (root) su - mainaccount`  This will let members of **mainusers** become **mainaccount** by using `su - mainaccount`.  By doing so as **root**, they don't need to give a password for the `su`-command.  Alternative `%mainusers ALL = (mainaccount) ALL` lets members of **mainusers** to run any command as **mainaccount**.

Let **mainaccount**-user be member of the **sudo**-group (ie. may `sudo` to **root** and run commands as **root**).  This will let any user first becomming **mainaccount** to then use `sudo`to become **root**.

---

That said, this sounds like a *bad idea!*  It may be better to let **mainaccount** - and users belonging to **mainusers** who could become him - to only be allowed to run a *limited number* of privileged commands (perhaps only the commands in a dedicated directory), maybe as **root**.  `sudo` can be used to set-up this too.

You may look at `man sudoers` -- and in the example sudoers-file in /usr/share/doc/sudo/examples/ -- for more inspiration.  Look especially how they use alias and the **operator**-user/group in the example-file. Here "operators" may do daily maintenance work -- like shut-down the computer, kill processes, start/stop/add printers, mount CDROMs, and such things -- but *far* from everything **root** (and members of **sudo**-group) can do.  This is a more appropriate set-up for allowing "trusted users" doing some day-to-day admin-work.  If you're running several computers, it may also be a good idea to limit their privileges to only one or two computers (eg. groups of users have special rights on "their" computer, but not on the other computers).

So if I was you, I would think twice and perhaps rethink this - especially the number of users you intend to "promote".  If you *have to* do this; I would suggest the **operator**-solution - put them in a group, and use `sudo` to give them *a limited set* of privileged commands they could run (as **root**) to fix day-to-day problems.  But *don't* let them all be able to ascend to full **root**-status!  If you *really* need someone with full **root**-privileges, then pick a couple among the dozen that you *really trust* and *knows* are knowledgeable, and add them to the **sudo**-group as full co-administrators... that would be a lot cleaner and easier to control than what you proposed.

Comment: agreed as a bad idea, it was a requirement and talked people off of this idea, thank you so much!